# WPF synchronize sizes of ListBox's items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I am using the following xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="Lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >            
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" >
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Id" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Id}" />

                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new
    {
        Items = new object[]
        {
            new {Id = 1, Name = "John"},
            new {Id = 2, Name = "John Smith"},
            new {Id = 3, Name = "Andrew"},
            new {Id = 4, Name = "Andrew Wright"},
            new {Id = 5, Name = "Arthur"},
            new {Id = 6, Name = "Arthur Williams"},
            new {Id = 7, Name = "another name"},
            new {Id = 8, Name = "another name and surname"}
        }
    };
}
```

And now I've get this result:

[image]

As you can see the items in ListBox are of different sizes because properties name of `DataContext` are different. But I would like to get this items with the similar sizes like this:

[image]

Could you help me with this question? Thank in advance!

Comment: What would you like your boxes to look? Your names aren't John... we cannot know what you want, please show an example.

Comment: i want my boxes have the same sizes independently their content.

Comment: And what size? The size of "John" or the size of the longest or do you need word wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use grid column `SharedSizeGroup` property ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Try this:

```
<ListBox Name="Lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" >
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Id" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Id}" />

                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set **`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"`** on your ListBox and for columns specify **`SharedSizeGroup`** so that all columns share same size (maximum among items).

This will get you desired result:

```
<ListBox Name="Lst" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Id" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Description}" />

                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```